# OpenTelemetry Collector, Prometheus, and K8s namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, open-telemetry

Given the below scenario (which I believe is quite standard) - how can the metrics know what namespaces they came from? They always seem to just refer to the monitoring namespace - which sortof makes sense given the shared OTel Collector is in that namespace, and that's what's being scraped. However, if this is the recommended OTel Collector pattern, and the Collector is effectively just a proxy/hub - I'm surprised that this isn't dealt with somehow. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: It would help if you'd share your collector config so we can see the concrete metrics pipeline but from what you describe I assume you're using the [Prometheus receiver](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/prometheusreceiver) inbound. If that's the case then the [Kubernetes service discovery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config) applies where the Kubernetes namespace info is captured in the meta label `__meta_kubernetes_namespace`.

Comment: Hi. No, for the receiver, we're just using normal OTLP. We're using the Prometheus exporter in the Collector (which exposed the Prom metrics as an endpoint in the Collector). Then using a Prometheus ServiceMonitor CR to scrape the Collector.
So is that the issue? OurService->Collector using OLTP loses the namespace information?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In the [Prometheus exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/prometheusexporter), have you set `resource_to_telemetry_conversion.enabled` to `true`?

Comment: Yep, I believe so. I'm kindof passing this on 3rd-hand now - as another developer on the team has been looking into this. But he says he's tried it, and I can see in Git that it's set against the Collector as per that documentation. From what he's said - the Collector isn't getting the source namespace in the first place. It might just be that we need to use the Prom receiver instead of OLTP to get the metrics into the Collector.

Comment: Actually - discovered this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/ - so looks like we can just enrich the metrics with an OTel attribute with the namespace from k8s taken from an environment variable. That should hopefully solve the issue 

Answer (score 0):

There are two other options available one is [kubelet /metrics/resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/system-metrics/) endpoint and the other is [Metrics api](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) which will be used purely for autoscaling purposes by kubernetes apiserver. The kubelet metrics endpoint documentation explains in detail how the metrics can be scrapped by prometheus or any other tool, hope this might help you